# JavaScript test RegEx always returning false

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to verify if a string looks like a valid e-mail address, however the function is always returning false regardless of what I type

```
function looksLikeMail(str) {
      var patt = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i);
      return patt.test(str);
    }

var c1;
var c2;
var error = false;
c1 = document.getElementById("t8").value;
c2 = document.getElementById("t9").value;
if (document.getElementById("t8").value != "" || document.getElementById("t9").value != ""){
     if (document.getElementById("t8").value != ""){
     var validE;
     validE = looksLikeMail((String)(t8));
     if (!validE){
        error = true;
        alert("invalid email address");
       }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-row">
  <label class="col align-self-center">&nbsp;<b>email (at least one)</b></label>
  </div>


  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
  <label for="inputEmail4">email-1</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="t8" placeholder="email">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
  <label for="inputEmail5">email-2</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="t9" placeholder="email">
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJzwOR?editors=1111 What valid email address do you have problems with?

Comment: Use *either* the RegExp constructor *or* regexp literal syntax.

Comment: Why do you assign the variables `c1` and `c2`, but then not use them?

Answer (score 1):

Your `looksLikeMail` is fine (returns true for 'a@a.com').

The rest of your JS though seems problematic. For one, your variable `t8` is never defined. Also, `(String)` is invalid syntax. To cast in JS, you could do `String(t8)` instead. That being said, this is unnecessary because `input.value` will return a string anyways.

Since you seem unfamiliar with JS, i've done some small cleanup as well:

```
let t8 = document.getElementById("t8").value;
if (t8) {
     let validE = looksLikeMail(t8);
     if (!validE){
        error = true;
        alert("invalid email address");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        function looksLikeMail(str){
            var regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return regex.test(str);
        }

        looksLikeMail("aa@aa.cc");// true
        looksLikeMail("aa@aa.c");// false
        looksLikeMail("demo_a-su@abcca.cd.bc");// true
```

Also you can test the regex here

https://regex101.com/r/777dwJ/1

Regex credits to.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/5708097

Comment: You should explain what you changed and how it solves the problem.

Comment: well, basically  im using another regex pattern

Comment: Don't make this a challenge to find the difference. Explain what's wrong with his pattern.